# I want to move something out of an initialisation list, how should I do it?

Tags: c++, initialization

Previously I had:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : myMember(VALUE,this,5,"etc.") { ... }
```

but I need to do some calculation of the values passed to myMember's constructor. How do I initialise `myMember` within the constructor body instead? I'm not sure if I should do it like this:

```
MyMember myMember(calculatedValue,this,5,"etc.");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All member initialisation occurs before the constructor body runs.  So if you did this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    myMember = MyMember(calculatedValue,this,5,"etc.");
}
```

it would be assignment, not initialisation.  So it won't work if `MyMember`s are not assignable (e.g. they have a private assignment operator).  It also won't work if `myMember` is declared as `const`.

You could, however, do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : myMember(calculate(VALUE),this,5,"etc.") {}

private:
    static int calculate(int x) { return x*3; }
};
```

or even something like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : myMember(createMember()) {}

private:
    static MyMember createMember(int x) {
        MyMember m;
        m.foo = 5;
        ...
        return m;
    }
};
```

Note that I've used `static` helper functions here, because using non-`static` member functions before the constructor has completed gets a little weird, in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the `myMember` member inside `MyClass`' constructor, you are really invoking `MyMember`'s default costructor, then invoking the assignment operator.

If it's fine for you, then you just need to write:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    myMember = MyMember(calculatedValue,this,5,"etc.");
}
```

otherwise, you need a different approach.